# Distributed Transaction across two EJB server

Tags: transactions, ejb, jta, distributed-transactions, 2phase-commit

I was reading an article about 2-PC and distributed transaction in EJB server. It says:

> A 2-PC allows transactions to be managed across different servers and
>       resources (e.g., databases and JMS providers). The details of a 2-PC are beyond the
>       scope of this book, but a system that supports it will not require any extra operations
>       by an EJB or application developer.
>
> In addition to managing transactions in its own environment, an EJB server can coordinate
>       with other transactional systems. If, for example, an EJB actually came from a
>       different application server than the BankEJB, the two application servers would
>       cooperate to manage the transaction as one unit-of-work.

If I've two different Enterprize Apps (A and B) running on two app-server that are hosted in two different machines. The application servers that I'm using will be WebLogic and Oracle AS. Is it possible that 2 PC/distributed transaction will co-ordinate the transaction across the two servers (even, if they are from different vendors)? Let me know, If my question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the EJB spec requires EJB containers to either implement transaction interoperability using OTS or to throw an exception.

In practice, it appears that WebLogic does implement transaction interoperability:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jta/trxsvc.html#wp1056344

...but OC4J does not:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12314_01/web.904/b10326/interop.htm